# Upgrading Team Site for TFS from Sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, tfs, upgrade

We are currently using TFS 2010 and have a Team site of SharePoint 2007. We are currently not using the Team site (we tried out a few things but at the moment its no problem to just remove it).

But we want to use the Team site and thought that we might as well upgrade it to 2010 before starting to use it. Its probably easier to upgrade from a pretty clean install than doing it later.

So.. Is it best to upgrade our site.. or should we maybe install a new SharePoint 2010 on the side and then switch over to that?

Any suggestions on which approach i should take. What is easiest (I don't know if I need to install anything special for Team site than other SharePoint sites)

PS. I am a newbie when it comes to SharePoint but can get some more experienced help if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to install a new Sharepoint 2010 instance somewhere and point TFS to that.  To set it up you need to install SP 2010, then install the SP TFS Extensions off the TFS Install DVD, then fire up TFS Admin console and use it to configure the SP site.  More detailed instructions can be found here: http://blog.hinshelwood.com/integrate-sharepoint-2010-with-team-foundation-server-2010/

Once you've got it configured it will auto-create Team Portals for any new Team Projects.  If you wish to create Portals for pre-existing Team Projects there is a manual step you need to take that is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggboer/archive/2010/02/24/creating-sharepoint-portals-reports-and-upgrading-reports-for-an-existing-team-project.aspx